# 'arguments' is only allowed in functions and class methods React

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React component that updates a few things.

I am getting this error when I try to run it:

> 'arguments' is only allowed in functions and class methods.

The error is in thos component, in the `updateConnection` function:

```
import { updateConnection } from '../connections';

export default class Connection extends React.PureComponent {

    updateConnection = (name, value, save = true) => {
        if (arguments.length === 0) {
            updateConnection(this.state.connection);
            return;
        }
```

The `updateConnection` that is imported, is just a simple API call:

```
export function updateConnection(connection) {
    return api.put(`/api/connections/${connection.id}`, connection);
}
```

But `updateConnection` is a function...so why would it give me that error?

Full error:

```
SyntaxError: G:\ConnectMe\Connect\Client\Connector\components\Connection.js: 'arguments' is only allowed in functions and class methods. (124:12)
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: there is no `arguments` in arrow function

Comment: @super sorry, I just added it.  Thanks!

Comment: @kerm I'm sorry I don't understand?  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the `arguments` keyword in an arrow function. The keyword `arguments` cannot be used in arrow functions.

```js
const myFunction = () => {
  // cannot use arguments in an arrow function
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

to use arguments in an arrow function, you can use the spread operator

```js
const myFunction = (...args) => {
  console.log(args); // args contains function's arguments as an Array
}
```

Though, in function declarations, you can use the `arguments` keyword.

```js
function myFuction () {
 console.log(arguments); // can be used here
}
```

Or, you can use it in class methods

```
class MyClass {
  classMethod () {
    console.log(arguments); // can be used here
  }
}
```